# Conversão de foto para base64 com erro 414 (Request-URI Too Long)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

Eu tenho o códido a baixo que faz a conversão de uma foto para base *string64* envia a base via *AJAX* para o *controller*, porém ao passar para o método do 
ajax, retorno o seguinte erro:

A conversão da foto é feita sem erros.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe alguma maneira de encurtar/camuflar a base para poder evitar este erro?

Segue códigos:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

    });
    function mostraImagem(img) {
        if (img.files && img.files[0]) {
            var fileExtension = ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'bmp'];
            if ($.inArray($(img).val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase(), fileExtension) == -1) {
                swal('', 'Formato do arquivo inválido! Somente JPG, JPEG, PNG, BMP são permitidos.', 'warning');
                $("#FileUpload1").val('');
                $("#imgImage").val('');
                return false;

                sizes = input.files[0].size;
                if (parseInt(sizes) > 100000) {
                    swal("", "Tamanho do arquivo inválido! Tamanho máximo permitido 100 KB", 'warning');
                    $("#FileUpload1").val('');
                    $("#imgImage").val('');
                    return false;
                }
            }
            var reader = new FileReader();
            var imgConvertida = null;
            var imagem = document.getElementById("imgImage");
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                imagem.src = e.target.result;
                imgConvertida = imagem.src;
            };
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(img.files[0]);
        SetarImagem(imgConvertida);
    }
    function SetarImagem(imgConvertida) {
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/MeusDados/SetarImagem?img=" + imgConvertida,
                //data: "{'img': '" + img + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    //alert(data);
                }
            });

        }

</script>


<div class="dois_quintos">
    <input type="file" ID="FileUpload1" onChange="mostraImagem(this);" />
    <br />
    @if (Model.CliFoto != null)
    {
        <img ID="imgImage" src="data:image/jpg;base64, @Convert.ToBase64String(Model.CliFoto)" style="width: 143px; height: 138px;" />
    }
    else
    {

        <img ID="imgImage" src="~/images/avatarDefault.png" style="width: 143px; height: 138px;" />
    }

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente o seu problema é que você está passando o base64 na url, isso não pode, pois o url tem um tamanho máximo. Por isso que você recebe o erro mencionado em sua pergunta.

Para resolver o seu problema a única forma e passar a stirng do base64 no parâmetro data da requisição ajax.

```
function SetarImagem(imgConvertida) {
    var vData = {
        img: imgConvertida
    };

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/MeusDados/SetarImagem,
            data: vData,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                //alert(data);
            }
    });
}
```